# Integral of a translated Borel function is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure $\mu$. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ be Borel measurable, and let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be Borel measurable with $\mu(E) > 0$.

Define $F(t) = \int_E f(x+t) d\mu(x)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am tasked with showing that $F(t) $ is then also Borel measurable. I think I need to somehow use the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure, but I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Do you know that translation is continuous in $L^1?$

Answer (score 0):

If f is integrable then this F is actually continuous. This is a standard fact and a proof can be found in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. For the general case let $f_n$ be the minimum of f and n on (-n,n) and 0 elsewhere. An application of Monotone Convergence Theorem shows that F is the limit of a sequence of continuous functions.